# Struggling to prove inequality

Tags: calculus, integration, inequality, integral-inequality

I've been given to following inequality to prove:

(The hint given was not to evaluate the integral)

\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{4} \leq \int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}}\frac{sin(x)}{x}dx\leq \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}.
\end{equation*}

(I see that $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ is $sin(\frac{\pi}{3})$ and I have been trying to prove it using the comparative properties of the Integral)

Comment: You can use the increasing property of $\sin (x)$ within $[\pi/6,\pi/3]$. $$\frac{3}{\pi}\sin(\pi/6)\leq \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\leq \frac{6}{\pi}\sin(\pi/3)$$

Answer (score 1):

As the function $\dfrac{\sin x}x$  decreases on every interval on which $\sin x$ and $x$  have the same sign, we can have better bounds:
$$ \frac{\sqrt 3}4=\frac3\pi \sin\frac\pi3\Bigl(\frac\pi3-\frac\pi6\Bigr)\le\int_{\tfrac{\pi}{6}}^{\tfrac{\pi}{3}}\frac{\sin x}{x}\,\mathrm d\mkern 1mu x\le \frac6\pi \sin\frac\pi6\Bigl(\frac\pi3-\frac\pi6\Bigr)=\frac12 $$